# How to import numbers from txt file with spaces and plot it

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code I have is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)

plt.plot(x,y, label='test')


plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('F10.7 flux')
plt.title('Solar Cycle 23')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The data.txt file contains 4,000 entries of the date YYYY MM DD, number:

```
1996 08 01, 82.8
1996 08 02, 81.9
1996 08 03, 81.6
1996 08 04, 79.9
1996 08 05, 76.2
1996 08 06, 75.1
```

and I'm getting the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1996 08 01'
```

How do I convert it to a string and still have it displayed properly on the graph?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for that. In particular the [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function, that returns a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).

The problem is not the 4000 points. But the `x` is a string (the date is as string). Try converting them to `datetime` to make it easier to manage.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', names=['date', 'value'])

# We convert the str to datetime
x = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
y = df.value

plt.plot(x,y, label='test')

plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('F10.7 flux')
plt.title('Solar Cycle 23')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: test_plot]

Be careful that df.date and df.value It's not the array, it's the [pandas Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html).
To access the values (the array only):

```
x = df.date.values
y = df.value.values
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas, datetime information can be parsed during DataFrame creation by using `parse_dates=[0]`, specifying that the first column is expected to contain datetime data.

Side note; there is no need to take the intermediate step of assigning the df columns to x and y.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('solar.txt', names=['date', 'value'], parse_dates=[0])
plt.plot(df.date, df.value, label='test')
plt.xticks(rotation='45')

plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('F10.7 flux')
plt.title('Solar Cycle 23')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]